# Hover fast slideshow error

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a slideshow and I have links to the images on the slideshow.

When the mouse enters the links, the slideshow pauses and plays when the mouse leaves.

My problem is that the slideshow appears to get faster and faster when you quickly move the mouse across the links.

```
function begin_slideshow() {
     some code
}
```

and the mouse enter/leave function

```
element.on('mouseenter', function () {
                var url = $(this).data('loc').replace('_t', '');//grabs the image
                fig.attr("src", url);//changes the source
                $('.shown').removeClass('shown');//the link that can be seen has a class of shown
                $(this).addClass('shown');//adds class of shown to the now showing link 
                clearTimeout(timer);
            }).on('mouseleave', function () {
                timer = setTimeout(begin_slideshow, 5000);
            });
```

I think the problem lies in the hover somewhere, hopefully you can help :) as I am truly stuck.

EDIT

http://jsfiddle.net/uYMkr/8/

Comment: Add a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your problem would lie in the timeout. However it seems correct. Therefor I would think the problem exists in either your usage of the slideshowcode, or in the slideshowcode itself. Can you post that?

Comment: thanks, I have just added a jsfiddle example to show what I have at the moment

Comment: I see you create an anonymous timeout in your slideshow code, try replacing "timer = setTimeout(begin_slideshow, 5000);" with an interval and remove the anonymous timeout.